# Cartopy not running even with basic introductory example

Tags: python, valueerror, cartopy

I have installed Cartopy and am now trying to run the basic example code snippet on the tutorial website just to check everything is working:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()

plt.savefig('coastlines.pdf')
plt.savefig('coastlines.png')

plt.show()
```

I get the following ValueError back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mattbright/Desktop/SCripts/lattice_geo.py", line 6, in <module>
    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mollweide())
  File "/Users/mattbright/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 947, in axes
    return subplot(111, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mattbright/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1125, in subplot
    ax = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mattbright/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1402, in add_subplot
    ax = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mattbright/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 42, in __init__
    self._axes_class.__init__(self, fig, self.figbox, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mattbright/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 355, in __init__
    super(GeoAxes, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mattbright/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 511, in __init__
    self.cla()
  File "/Users/mattbright/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 528, in cla
    self._boundary()
  File "/Users/mattbright/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 1425, in _boundary
    trans_path = proj_to_data.transform_path(path)
  File "/Users/mattbright/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 1527, in transform_path
    return self.transform_path_affine(self.transform_path_non_affine(path))
  File "/Users/mattbright/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 181, in transform_path_non_affine
    src_path.vertices, self.source_projection)
  File "/Users/mattbright/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cartopy/crs.py", line 649, in quick_vertices_transform
    if (x.min() >= x_limits[0] and x.max() <= x_limits[1] and
  File "/Users/mattbright/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 43, in _amin
    return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

I tried the installation with conda and with pip3 plus the list of dependencies given on the website.

There's one previous question about this issue which has gone unanswered since the questioner claimed that an Anaconda reinstall solved the problem. A similar issue with Seaborn has been raised here and solved by reverting to an earlier Matplotlib release (3.3.0)

None of these solutions have worked for me. Has anybody else encountered this and found a way to fix it?

Comment: the first line of your traceback says `ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mollweide())`. can you make sure you post the code which corresponds to your error?

Comment: that said, both projections work fine for me with your code. you can run into all kinds of nasty errors if your environment has packages from multiple channels (e.g. `defaults` and `conda-forge`). I can see you're running with miniconda (great!) but you can still get this issue if you're installing into your base env with a mix and match. Can you try deleting your env (sorry) and then installing again with [`miniforge`](//github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) or `mambaforge` (it's much faster, compiled cousin lower down on the same page), both of which set `conda-forge` as the priority channel?

Comment: Thanks very much! The problem was indeed clearly due to some sort of clash in all the different background packages. I've fixed it by installing everything in its own virtual environment from scratch.